# Multi-line Row grid controls

Tags: .net, controls, grid, components, multiline

Does anyone know if there are any multi-line row grid controls for sale or open source for use in .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infragistics appears to do it.  I have used Infragistics; they are okay as far a third party tools go.  They are bug-free but have very verbose APIs.  Documentation is quite good.

http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=1043